# Chrome Extension onCreatedNavigationTarget Listener stops working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I added a listener with `chrome.webNavigation.onCreatedNavigationTarget.addListener` to the background.js with `webNavigation` in permissions into the manifest.json it worked fine when I tested it.

I skipped work on it for a few days and tried to continue after but the listener doesn't run the callback function at all. If I refresh it from the `chrome//extensions` it works again.
I didn't switch off this extension and didn't refresh before. It looks like this subscription has a timeout.

**Update:**
The code.

The permissions and background section from manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation",
    "downloads",
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage"
  ],
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  }
```

And part of the background.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCreatedNavigationTarget.addListener(async (details) => {
    const url = new URL(details.url);
    const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search.substr(1));

    chrome.tabs.remove(details.tabId);
    await startDownload(params);
  }, { url: [{ urlContains: 'localhost/formats' }] });
```

**Update:**

I've found how to reproduce this issue.
If I close Chrome and reopen it the listener is not added at all. I need to refresh the extension from the `chrome//extensions` and it works after that. background.js is not run after reopening Chrome.

Comment: There's no timeout. Assuming it's not a bug in the browser there's probably a mistake in your code so add it to the question. And show your manifest.json's "background" section.

Comment: @wOxxOm added :)

Comment: Try remove `async` from function definition

Comment: @AloyanDmitry I tried. Check my last update in the question.

Comment: @AndrewZaikin how you close Chrome? Complete kill process? In MacOs Chrome continue working after closing via "red button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, thanks @AloyanDmitry.
In the background.js I have `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {})`
It means that the extension will start working just after installing it. If you have already installed the extension after restart Chrome it will not start working.